# Markdown-preview does't work in emacs markdown mode

Tags: emacs, markdown

#### Markdown preview command doesn't work.

I installed markdown-mode.el on emacs by using package-install.
Then I created test.md file as a trial. Syntax hi-lighting apparently works fine in the text.

When I used "C-c C-c p" command in order to show markdown preview, I got following error message in **backtrace** buffer. Even if I saved test.md file in current directory, it still said "No such file or directory". The file is located in "~/workspace/daily_log/test.md."

I tried "M-x markdown-preview" instead of shortcut key. But it doesn't work,too.

Do I make a mistake about usage of markdown-mode? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

#### Error message in backtrace buffer

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Searching for program" "No such file or directory" "bash.exe")
call-process-region(1 36 "bash.exe" "/tmp/emacsAxnXZ9" #<buffer *markdown-output*> nil "-c" "markdown")
shell-command-on-region(1 36 "markdown" "*markdown-output*")
markdown("*markdown-output*")
markdown-preview()
call-interactively(markdown-preview nil nil)
command-execute(markdown-preview)
```

#### my environment

OS: Ubuntu 14.10

emacs: 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.12.2)

markdown-mode: markdown-mode-20140914.1012/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you inspect the backtrace you'll see that this has nothing to do with your Markdown file.

`markdown-preview` needs an external `markdown` command that can generate HTML. It looks like whatever Markdown processor you are using is trying to call `bash.exe` (not `bash`) when converting your file.

- You might have installed some Windows-centric Markdown converter.
- You might have customized `markdown-command`, directly or indirectly causing it to call `bash.exe`.

Since you are on Ubuntu, a simple `apt-get install markdown` should give you a decent Markdown that works with `markdown-mode`'s `markdown-preview` function. After installing `markdown` at the system level, make sure that Emacs has `markdown-command` set to `markdown` (the default value).

Comment: Thank you for rapid reply. As a result, the problem has been resolved. I owe my success to you. First of all, I need install markdown command by apt-get. And I had to correct  my .emacs/init.el. Because I use emacs on the both of MS Windows and Ubuntu, there are some platform dependent code in init.el. for example,  `(setq shell-file-name "bash.exe") ` . this is my fault.

Comment: `sudo apt install libtext-multimarkdown-perl` worked for me in ubuntu